# Output multi digit numbers to console LC3

Tags: assembly, logic, lc3

I take in 2 user entered multiple digit numbers, and I store these in R5 and R6.
It follows to the subroutine below. I am trying to print them to console. My end goal is to get the sum and difference of these numbers. Right now I am simply trying to get them to output properly to the console, but they simply come out as gibberish.

My subroutine:

```
    .ORIG x3200
    AND     r0, r0, #0  ;CLEARS Registers
    AND     R1, R1, #0
    AND R2, R2, #0
    AND     R3, R3, #0

    ADD R1, R1, R5  ;R5 Val stored in R1
    LD  R2, PLUS30  ;Loads ASCII to convert Num->ascii text


FOR_LOOP
    LDR R4, R1, #0  ; load the contents of mem address of R1 into R4
    BRz END_LOOP
    ADD R4, R4, R2  ;ADD num to ASCII offset
    STR R4, R1,#0   ;Store new val in R4 into mem address of R1
    ADD R1, R1, #1  ;Move Pointer Down 1
    BRnzp   FOR_LOOP    ;loop until x00 char
END_LOOP    
    PUTS            ;print R0
    HALT


MINUS30 .FILL x-30
PLUS30  .FILL x30
Num1    .FILL x4000
Num2    .FILL x4001
    .END
```

This prints gibberish to the console, and I cant make sense of it. However if I simply load R5 into R1, and withdraw the lines with the comments above, the number does print, simply with a few ý's in front.

Any ideas how to get it to output properly?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure `x-30` is the correct way to write it? I would guess `-x30`. Anyway, run it through your simulator and see where it goes wrong. Also, comment your code especially if you want others to help. PS: To convert to text you need to add `0x30` not subtract.

Comment: I added comments, and made the change to add it. Still showing errors. Also it should be written as x-30 not -x30.